# (Custom) bullet point infront of each HTML Table Row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

My thought was to make a table out of this and then add bullet points in front of each table row, however, I realized this is not working out, I can't add bullet points to table rows. Is this possible at all with a table or do I need to us an unordered list (or even simply div's?)

Comment: You can make this happen with css but you would need to add some code for a more meaningful answer.

Comment: @Stavros Angelis You mean I can make this happen as a HTML table?

Comment: Yes you can add an html element in the first cell of each row, pull it to the left to appear outsite the table (maybe margin-left: -50px) and form it into a bullet point (maybe border-radius: 50%; background-color: red).

Comment: Is there a 'cleaner' way to achieve this? I'dont want to work with negative margins, also this has to work for mobile, it doesn't necessarily need to be a table

Comment: I would personally avoid the table approach and go with a hierarchy of div layers but it depends on how experienced you are. The table may help you keep things in place (e.g the height of each row, columns width aligning etc) but at the same time you may find that restrictive.

Comment: Yes that's what I will go for, I was just wondering if there is a simple solution with tables that I'm missing.. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have used pseudo-element and position for the desired output.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/ydk0v4bf/1/

```css
.table-container {
  padding-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.table-container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  left: 20px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td {
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  position: relative;
}

table tr td:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: -40px;
  top: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}

table tr td:first-child:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: -32px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus quisquam iusto delectus deleniti maiores quam similique molestiae, blanditiis qui, beatae, debitis quidem pariatur amet maxime ipsum? Laudantium voluptate perferendis esse.</td>
      <td>Demo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus quisquam iusto delectus deleniti maiores quam similique molestiae, blanditiis qui, beatae, debitis quidem pariatur amet maxime ipsum? Laudantium voluptate perferendis esse.</td>
      <td>Demo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus quisquam iusto delectus deleniti maiores quam similique molestiae, blanditiis qui, beatae, debitis quidem pariatur amet maxime ipsum? Laudantium voluptate perferendis esse.</td>
      <td>Demo</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This works quite good! I'm running into a problem when I add headers, the read line should stop where the first row begins, instead it goes up all they way where the header begins (https://jsfiddle.net/atgm6jeh/), do you know a solution for that?

Comment: If you are using Heading please refer to this link https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/fkL0btc5/1/